# Point light shadow mapping and lighting shader

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow

I'm doing omni directional shadow mapping and one thing I cannot grasp is during the lighting stage, how does one get the vector to use in sampling the cubemap?

In the shadow pass I just use the depth values, so I need to be in the same space now. But how do I know which of the six view matrices to use (as it is one for each face) to convert the world space position into the NDC space?

For example, using [this](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/174093-GLSL-cube-shadows-projecting?p=1219162&viewfull=1#post1219162) as a reference, looking at the fragment shader there is a "light_view_matrix" - but what is it? Light view matrix... of what face? I generated one for each face during shadow pass.

Comment: If you do lighting in world-space, you don't need to bother with any of that. A view matrix transforms from world-space to view-space, by the way. You would need a projection matrix to go any farther than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a very in-depth tutorial on shadow mapping with the programmable pipeline, check out [Tutorial 16: Shadow mapping](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/)

A quote on the site about Point lights:

> Point lights
>
> Same thing, but with depth cubemaps. A cubemap is a set of 6 textures, one on each side of >a cube; what’s more, it is not accessed with standard UV coordinates, but with a 3D vector >representing a direction.
>
> The depth is stored for all directions in space, which make possible for shadows to be >cast all around the point light.

Comment: Do be careful for vectors that point to the edge between one face in the cubemap and another. Traditionally, GPUs did not filter texels from multiple cubemap faces in this case and you will get a very weird discontinuity on these corner cases if you try to implement something like hardware PCF or filtered VSM. DX10 class hardware supports seamless cubemaps though. Look at [`GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/seamless_cube_map.txt) for more details; it is *disabled* by default even on hardware that supports it.

Comment: Many engines actually use the same fundamental concept behind cubemap shadow mapping, but instead of storing them as an actual cubemap they are unrolled into a 2D texture and write a special texture lookup function of their own. This helps a little bit with filtering between cubemap faces on pre-DX10 hardware (e.g. Xbox 360/PS3) and it makes packing the shadow maps into a giant atlas much easier. CryEngine, for example, does this.